# the translation does not work Help Please help Cake Php

Tags: cakephp, translate

**here is the line from home.ctp**

```
<div id="bid-now" class="border-blue">
    <div class="heading bg-image-blue"><h3>BID NOW! - these auctions are about to end</h3></div>
    <?php echo $this->element('bid_now!_-_these_auctions_are_about_to_end'); ?>
    <div class="content">
```

**and here is the line from Language File**

```
#: /views/auctions/home.ctp:20
msgid "BID NOW! - these auctions are about to end"
msgstr "BIETEN SIE JETZT! - Diese Auktionen sind kurz vor dem Ende"
```

**I've translated everything, some translations work and others don't. can someone help me ?**

Comment: There's no use of any [**translation functions**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#using-translation-functions) in your code snippet.

Comment: that's cakephp version 2.6 what i have

Comment: The version doesn't matter; if you want your text translated, you have to pass it through a translation function.